# Convert fixed price bundles to dynamic priced bundles

Tags: magento-1.8, bundled-product, bundle

I need to convert a fixed price bundle to a dynamic price bundle. Does anyone have a solution that is easy to implement on bulk?

Comment: [@TrentWold](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/31010/3906) Thanks. That worked with default magento import too. Previously I tried to change dynamic price to fixed from admin that didn't work. But import did the trick. Next task for me is to hide price when bundled item price is $0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had to do this recently and it was fairly straight forward. Fortunately Fixed/Dynamic price is easily updatable. 
First I exported the existing bundled products, the default dataflow profile "export Products" under System->Import/Export->Dataflow Profiles. This has a filter for product type that you can set to bundled before export.

You may also consider using the column mapper to limit the number of columns exported. We will only need columns: 
store,sku,price_type.

Once you have that exported it is just a matter of updating the price_type column to match your desired setting, either 1 or 0. 
0 = Dynamic or 1 = Fixed

I then use Magmi to load this file back into magento. This worked flawlesly when I needed to update about 4,000 bundled products in bulk. 
 I assume you could probably use the default import tool as well but I cannot say that I've tried that.

Answer (score 2):

Another slightly bodgey, but very quick and simple way to do this is to open the product page in the admin where the price dropdown to change between 'fixed' and 'dynamic' is greyed out and disabled, then to use your browser developer tools to select the dropdown element and to remove the 'disabled="disabled"' out of the  element, then press enter to commit the change and close developer tools and you will find that you can then change this value and save.
I've confirmed this works in Magento 1.9.1.1

### Disabled Dropdown:

[image: disabled dropdown]

### Dropdown Re-enabled:

[image: dropdown re-enabled]

*(click screenshots to enlarge)*